# Adding external JAR file in Gradle project on Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having a terrible time adding an external JAR to my gradle project in Android Studio. I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046095/how-can-i-add-a-jar-in-my-gradle-project) but those answers haven't worked for me.

I created a `libs` folder and added my JAR in there:

```
~/android/MyProject/libs $ pwd
/Users/me/android/MyProject/libs
~/android/MyProject/libs $ ls
TestFlightLib.jar
```

And I added the following in my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

After doing all this I clicked `Build -> Rebuild` project but that still doesn't let me add `import com.testflightapp.lib.TestFlight`

I also tried the second solution of right clicking `TestFlightLib.jar` and adding it as a Module. This lets me add `import com.testflightapp.lib.TestFlight` successfully but when I `Run` the project I still get the error: `Gradle: error: package com.testflightapp.lib does not exist`

What am I doing wrong?

How can I simply add an external JAR to my gradle project?

Comment: Don't ask a second, duplicate question just because you don't get a satisfactory answer to your question within 2 hours of asking it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- right click on your project
- choose "open module settings"
- click on module, then "dependencies"
- check that your file exists in the list
- if not, press + and add it as a file

Answer (score 0):

try this:`compile files('libs/x.jar', 'libs/y.jar')`