# How to add custom JARs with poms to a Gradle build?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have several JAR files, each with its own pom.xml file describing its dependencies.
For example:

1. one.jar depends on guava
2. two.jar depends on one.jar and some other 3rd party
3. three.jar depends on two.jar

I would like to create a project which depends on all those jars.

if it's a Maven project, then I simply install the JARs to my .m2 with their poms and Maven does all the rest for me.

The question is what is the correct way to create a Gradle project depended on those JARs?

(I'm a total rookie in Gradle, read some tutorials and been searching for ways to achieve this with no luck so far)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to build.gradle file and add all jars
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
to your dependencies in the build.gradle then all the jars in the libs folder will be included.

Comment: refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046095/how-can-i-add-a-jar-in-my-gradle-project

Comment: I dont think this question is a duplicate of the one you linked, because he asked about including a file dependency with a POM, so with transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle uses the Maven repository technology and provides support for the local Maven repository. Just add `mavenLocal()` to your `repositories` block and you can use the dependencies you installed via Maven in your build.